# lmfit packages conflicting in Windows 10 using Anaconda Python 3.7

Tags: package, conda, python-3.7, lmfit

I'm trying to use a curve fitting package (lmfit) I did use several times in former times with Python 2.7. Since I moved to Python 3.7, I'm facing some problems on running my script. The error message I get is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit'".
If I try to reinstall/update the package (using whatever of the commands in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lmfit): it looks like there are conflicting packages in my pc. Here the screen of my prompt:
[prompt after using 'conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 lmfit'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuxQz.png)

Any hints on how to solve this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

just install with `pip install lmfit`.

Comment: Mr. Newille,

thanks for your comment. I'm afraid it is already installed. If I look for it with pip, the 1.0.2 version is installed.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip show lmfit
Name: lmfit
Version: 1.0.2
Summary: Least-Squares Minimization with Bounds and Constraints
Home-page: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/
Author: LMFit Development Team
Author-email: matt.newville@gmail.com
License: BSD-3
Location: c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: scipy, numpy, asteval, uncertainties

But still get 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit' if try running my script.

Comment: um, a package is installed but cannot be imported?  Check `sys.path`, and make sure you are running the same Python and pip.  Something may be wrong with your installation.    You may want to delete all of your `site-packages/lmfit*` folders and re-install with pip.